# Any way to disable js error from html,css,js (not from browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am having trouble with some js error seen mostly from IE 8.
So tell me how to fix it from my side by coding.

Also i dont want to disable js completely for IE.

Comment: That would kind of depend on the code you haven't shown, no?

Comment: Nobody is going to guess at what the error is or what code is producing it. Update question with details